# Why a folder in dropbox is no longer shared when I moved them

Tags: windows-10, dropbox

> You can rename or move your shared folders just like you would any
>   other folder on your hard drive or via the website. Even if you rename
>   it, **the folder will still remain shared**. However, changing the
>   name of the shared folder or its location will not change its name or
>   location in the Dropbox of other members.

https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/64

I moved some folder. Control x control v. And the folder is no longer shared.

Answer (score 1):

The method you use to move the folder is what likely broke the "share". If you **drag** a folder using Windows Explorer or Finder, Dropbox sees that as a single operation — a simple "change the location of this folder" request — and will maintain the shared status and share link. The folder's location is moved.

If you cut and paste the folder, Dropbox sees it as two unrelated things: first the folder is *deleted* (even if your computer has actually made a copy on its clipboard — but Dropbox doesn't necessarily know that) and then some time later when you hit "paste", whether moments or hours later, a folder is being *created* with a bunch of content in it (which your computer dumps in from its clipboard). But it's a new folder, a new copy.

The difference between *cut/paste* versus *dragging* to move folders doesn't make a lot of difference to us: different means to the same end — but it's very different from a file system's point of view.

To keep shares and links alive, either stick to dragging folders (you can open multiple Explorer/Finder windows if it helps), or use the Dropbox web interface - right-click a folder and choose "Move..." on the pop up menu.

Answer (score 0):

> If you move a shared folder inside of another shared folder—perhaps
>   while organizing your Dropbox—the folder will change locations and
>   break any shared links. Shared folders cannot be "nested" within
>   another folder, and this action will register that you have opted to
>   leave the shared folder. Moving a shared folder into another folder
>   means you will no longer see changes collaborators make to files
>   within that folder. However, this nesting does not affect other users.
>
> https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/64